# Same Bundle Id + Different Developer Accounts

Tags: iphone, code-signing, provisioning

We followed following steps and found strange output. 
What would be possible reasons for these?

**Steps:**
    Created ipa's for 2 different applications using 2 different distribution profiles (both the profiles belongs to 2 different developer accounts) but keeping bundle id same.

**Actual Output:**  Both ipa's where treated as same i.e. 2nd ipa overridden the 1st one.

**Expected Output:** Both ipa's should be treated as different i.e. 2nd ipa shouldn't override 1st one.

Surprisingly same output was observed for same applications.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS uses `bundle identifier` to distinguish applications from one another. If you sign two application using similar bundle identifier and try to install one after then it will show similar behavior(Actual output).

For example one application you `com.example.user.zzz` and another application has same id then `iOS` will treat them as same application. Installation/Removal of one over other will depend on the order of installation and application version.

So in your case you should provide two different bundle ids so that `iOS` can distinguish them.

Thanks,

Comment: Ya you are right. But both bundle identifier belongs to different developer account & it might be possible that account holder of two different developer account can register same bundle id. Am I right?

Comment: It will not be possible, because at the time of creation of accounts if you use similar company identifier than apple will say you that its already taken. com.example.user.* can only be issued to one account.